# Custom deserialisation of XML in Django Tastypie

Tags: xml, django, xml-serialization, tastypie

I have a model resource which returns, a list of foreign keys.
When serialising to XML Tastypie creates the following:

```
<object>
    <friends type='list'>
        <object>....</object>
        <object>....</object>
        <object>....</object>    
</object>
```

However, when i post to my server from a client i would rather send the following XML

```
<object>
    <friends>
        <friend>....</friend>
        <friend>....</friend>
        <friend>....</friend>
     </friends>
</object>
```

I assume i have to write my own serialiser and change the behavior of the serialiser, but i am hoping for an easier solution.

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a custom solution, using lxml.etree to manage the data structure of my response. I think that Tastypie in its support for XML. You either accept the way the data is serialised/deserialised or you write your own entry_points. Using the built in django template engine proved useful.